# xslt 3.0 mapping and validation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have an Input file and Source file of courses in a combined xml. I m using xslt3.0 I need to validate Instructor id ,Location/Room with the given source xml
Source xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<FileAndCourses>
    <Maps>
        <Locations>
            <Location>
                <InternalValue>7070</InternalValue>
                <ExternalValue>Laval</ExternalValue>
            </Location>
                    </Locations>
            <Rooms>
                <Room>
                    <InternalValue>LOCATION-6-3881</InternalValue>
                    <ExternalValue>Ottawa District Training Center</ExternalValue>
                </Room>
            </Rooms>  
            
    </Maps>
    <Instructors>
        <Instructor>
        <InstructorID>119417764</InstructorID>
        <WorkdayUserName>AXH4006</WorkdayUserName>
    </Instructor>
        <Instructor>
            <InstructorID>713400041</InstructorID>
            <WorkdayUserName>TXB786</WorkdayUserName>
        </Instructor>
        <Instructor>
            <InstructorID>713500126</InstructorID>
            <WorkdayUserName>LXF99S</WorkdayUserName>
        </Instructor>
    </Instructors>
      <AllCourses
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
                <wd:Learning_Course>
            <wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2b24f4f5c40000</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">00151744</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:ID>
            </wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
            <wd:Learning_Course_Data>
                <wd:ID>00151744</wd:ID>
                <wd:Effective_Date>2014-10-04</wd:Effective_Date>
                <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                <wd:Course_Title>Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:Course_Title>
                <wd:Description>Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:Description>
                <wd:Course_Number>00151744</wd:Course_Number>
                <wd:Topic_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d1f49654c8310154e239c7090fc0000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Topic">Product Knowledge - US</wd:ID>
                </wd:Topic_Reference>
                <wd:Language_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da594226446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="User_Language_ID">en_US</wd:ID>
                </wd:Language_Reference>
                <wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>0</wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                <wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>0</wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                <wd:Waitlist_Capacity>0</wd:Waitlist_Capacity>
                <wd:Unlimited_Capacity>1</wd:Unlimited_Capacity>
                <wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                    <wd:Pricing_Enabled>0</wd:Pricing_Enabled>
                    <wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>0</wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>
                </wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                <wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f31be4fd5caa10001d7c625e27014929</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Time_Unit_ID">HOURS</wd:ID>
                </wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                <wd:Total_Course_Duration>18</wd:Total_Course_Duration>
                <wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>0</wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>
                <wd:Legacy_Course>1</wd:Legacy_Course>
                <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df56ab318140000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">100735117</wd:ID>
                </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018bbed7a460ce30000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">119417764</wd:ID>
                </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df57b8e81f30002</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">104034590</wd:ID>
                </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                <wd:All_Locations>0</wd:All_Locations>
                <wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>1</wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>
                <wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>0</wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>
                <wd:Disable_Express_Interest>1</wd:Disable_Express_Interest>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>1</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>2</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 2</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>3</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>4</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 4</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>5</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 5</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>6</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 6</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>7</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2b23247d3f0004</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">MEDIA-6-4195</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">MEDIA-6-4195</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Media_Reference>
                        <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Welcome to HDU Distance Learning</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                        <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                    </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>8</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>0</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">358e28e73d5d10109aef5b042fc20000</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">cninv000000000020562.zip</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">cninv000000000020562.zip</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Media_Reference>
                        <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Course Feedback HDUv3</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                        <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                    </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
            </wd:Learning_Course_Data>
        </wd:Learning_Course>
          <wd:Learning_Course>
              <wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2c78dc802e0001</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">00170024CA</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">Design Basics (Designer Training 4) - Virtual ILT</wd:ID>
              </wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
              <wd:Learning_Course_Data>
                  <wd:ID>00170024CA</wd:ID>
                  <wd:Effective_Date>2019-02-26</wd:Effective_Date>
                  <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                  <wd:Course_Title>Design Basics (Designer Training 4) - Virtual ILT</wd:Course_Title>
                  <wd:Description>&lt;p>In this 5 module virtual course the designer will learn the basics of drafting and laying out basic designs for Contractors and DIY customers.&lt;/p></wd:Description>
                  <wd:Course_Number>00170024CA</wd:Course_Number>
                  <wd:Topic_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d1f49654c8310154e4430e071ef0000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Topic">Customer Service and Selling Skills - CAN</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Topic_Reference>
                  <wd:Language_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da5948c0446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="User_Language_ID">en_CA</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Language_Reference>
                  <wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>4</wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                  <wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>10</wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                  <wd:Waitlist_Capacity>0</wd:Waitlist_Capacity>
                  <wd:Unlimited_Capacity>0</wd:Unlimited_Capacity>
                  <wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                      <wd:Pricing_Enabled>0</wd:Pricing_Enabled>
                      <wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>0</wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>
                  </wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                  <wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f31be4fd5caa10001d7c6231be3b4927</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Time_Unit_ID">MINUTES</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                  <wd:Total_Course_Duration>900</wd:Total_Course_Duration>
                  <wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>0</wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>
                  <wd:Legacy_Course>1</wd:Legacy_Course>
                  <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5cfa198ca0000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">718700459</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                  <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5c99611170000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">713400041</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                  <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5c72adbc60000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">702300581</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                  <wd:All_Locations>0</wd:All_Locations>
                  <wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>1</wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>
                  <wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>0</wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>
                  <wd:Disable_Express_Interest>1</wd:Disable_Express_Interest>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>1</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 1</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>2</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 2</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>3</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 3</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>4</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 4</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>5</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 5</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>6</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Media_Reference>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2c770c4c2b0003</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">MEDIA-6-4222</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">MEDIA-6-4222</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Media_Reference>
                          <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Log in Instructions (Adobe Connect - Designer 4_DesignBasics) (updated May 2022)</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                          <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                      </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>7</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>0</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Media_Reference>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="WID">358e28e73d5d1010910342e9c79a0000</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">cninv000000000019226.zip</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">cninv000000000019226.zip</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Media_Reference>
                          <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Course Evaluation - vILT (L1)</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                          <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                      </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
              </wd:Learning_Course_Data>
          </wd:Learning_Course>
                    </AllCourses>
       <Offerings>
        <Offering>
            <Lesson>
                <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
                <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
                 <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</Title>
                 <Facilitator-LDAP>AXH4006</Facilitator-LDAP>
                  <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
                  <Location/> 
                <Room>Ottawa District Training Center</Room>
            </Lesson>
            <Lesson>
                <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
                <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
                 <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</Title>
                 <Facilitator-LDAP></Facilitator-LDAP>
                  <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
                <Location>7070</Location> 
                <Room>Ottawa District Training </Room>
            </Lesson>
            
        </Offering>
           <Offering>
               
               <Lesson>
                   <Offering-ID>00170024CA - 2022 Group 12 - Thurs 10AM-1PM EST</Offering-ID>
                   <Course-Number>00170024CA</Course-Number>
                    <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                   <Title>Session 4</Title>
                                    <Facilitator-LDAP>TXB786</Facilitator-LDAP>
                                      <Webinar-URL>https://hdu-canada.adobeconnect.com/design_basics_2/</Webinar-URL>
                   <Location>Laval</Location> 
                   <Room/>
               </Lesson>
               <Lesson>
                   <Offering-ID>00170024CA - 2022 Group 12 - Thurs 10AM-1PM EST</Offering-ID>
                   <Course-Number>00170024CA</Course-Number>
                     <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                   <Title>Session 5</Title>
                   <Facilitator-LDAP>ZXF99S</Facilitator-LDAP>
                      <Webinar-URL>https://hdu-canada.adobeconnect.com/design_basics_2/</Webinar-URL>
                   <Location>Laval</Location> 
                   <Room/>
               </Lesson>
           </Offering>
         
            </Offerings>
</FileAndCourses>
```

My xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
    xmlns:xs=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    xmlns:map=http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:accumulator name="learning-course-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="lesson-mandatory" as="xs:boolean?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data" select="false()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory/text()" select=". = 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:accumulator name="webinars" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
            select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
            else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:accumulator name="classroom-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
            select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
            else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lesson-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Course-Number/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering" select="map{}"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Title/text()" 
            select="let $id := accumulator-before('offered-lesson-id')
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
            else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/FileAndCourses" expand-text="yes">
        <OfferingsWithCourse>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings/Offering"/>
        </OfferingsWithCourse>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Offering">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:variable name="webinars" select="accumulator-after('webinars')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="offered-lessons" select="accumulator-after('offered-lessons')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('webinars'))[. = map:keys($offered-lessons)]">
                <xsl:variable name="webinar-id" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$webinars(.)[not(. = $offered-lessons($webinar-id))]">
                    <Error>No matching required lesson found for title {.} in Course num {$webinar-id}</Error>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Lesson">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Offering/Lesson">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test="Course-Number = ''">
                <Error>
                    <xsl:text>Missing required field Course Number. </xsl:text>                                    
                </Error>
            </xsl:if>                         
            <xsl:if test="Facilitator-LDAP = ''">
                <Error>
                    <xsl:text>Missing required field Facilitator LDAP for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
                </Error>
            </xsl:if> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
      
    
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual output - Mapping logic not built

Expected output
1.)Need to map the Facilitator-LDAP with Instructor id
and also validate it is a valid instructor i.e WorkdayUserName should have Instructor id in the Instructor node
2.)Need to map Location/rooms and validate if it is not valid . this is not required field
(i.e) need to map internal value for a external value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfferingsWithCourse xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
                     xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
                     xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Offering>
      <Lesson>
         <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
         <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
         <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
         <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</Title>
         <Facilitator-LDAP>AXH4006</Facilitator-LDAP>
         <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
         <Location/>
         <Room>Ottawa District Training Center</Room>
         <InstructorID>119417764</InstructorID>
         <MappedLocation/>
         <MappedRoom>LOCATION-6-3881</MappedRoom>
      </Lesson>
      <Lesson>
         <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
         <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
         <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
         <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</Title>
         <Facilitator-LDAP/>
         <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
         <Location>7070</Location>
         <Room>Ottawa District Training </Room>
         <InstructorID/>
         <MappedLocation/>
         <MappedRoom/>
         <Error>Missing required field Facilitator LDAP for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </Error>
         <Error>Mapped location not found for 7070. </Error>
         <Error>Mapped room not found for Ottawa District Training . </Error>
      </Lesson>
   </Offering>
   <Offering>
      <Lesson>
         <Offering-ID>00170024CA - 2022 Group 12 - Thurs 10AM-1PM EST</Offering-ID>
         <Course-Number>00170024CA</Course-Number>
         <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
         <Title>Session 4</Title>
         <Facilitator-LDAP>TXB786</Facilitator-LDAP>
         <Webinar-URL>https://hdu-canada.adobeconnect.com/design_basics_2/</Webinar-URL>
         <Location>Laval</Location>
         <Room/>
         <InstructorID>713400041</InstructorID>
         <MappedLocation>7070</MappedLocation>
         <MappedRoom/>
      </Lesson>
      <Lesson>
         <Offering-ID>00170024CA - 2022 Group 12 - Thurs 10AM-1PM EST</Offering-ID>
         <Course-Number>00170024CA</Course-Number>
         <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
         <Title>Session 5</Title>
         <Facilitator-LDAP>ZXF99S</Facilitator-LDAP>
         <Webinar-URL>https://hdu-canada.adobeconnect.com/design_basics_2/</Webinar-URL>
         <Location>Laval</Location>
         <Room/>
         <InstructorID/>
         <MappedLocation>7070</MappedLocation>
         <MappedRoom/>
         <Error>Instructor ID not found for Workday account ZXF99S. </Error>
      </Lesson>
   </Offering>
</OfferingsWithCourse>
```

Comment: Your original question needed/wanted XSLT 3 with streaming. Do you still need streaming for this question? And anyway, you have two or three examples showing to collect data with accumulators, so where is your intent to set up one or a few more to stores instructors or locations to later check the elements in your Lesson against the accumulated/stored values?

Comment: Yes Martin , I need streaming with XSLT 3.  I m new  to streaming in xslt 3 and i m noting down the different patterns in data . kindly help in this pattern .Sorry to bother you

Comment: As I said, you have two or three examples of using accumulators to collect data and later compare them, so now try on your own to add additional accumulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example setting up two more accumulators to create a map of location external values to internal values plus two templates to use that accumulator map later on to output a mapped location or an error for a `Lesson`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
        
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="location-internal-value" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations/Location" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations/Location/InternalValue/text()" select="."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="location-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations" select="map{}"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations/Location/ExternalValue/text()" 
        select="map:put($value, string(), accumulator-before('location-internal-value'))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="learning-course-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="lesson-mandatory" as="xs:boolean?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data" select="false()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory/text()" select=". = 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="webinars" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
            select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
            else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:accumulator name="classroom-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
            select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
            else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        
    <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lesson-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Course-Number/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
        <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering" select="map{}"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Title/text()" 
            select="let $id := accumulator-before('offered-lesson-id')
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
            else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>
        
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/FileAndCourses" expand-text="yes">
        <OfferingsWithCourse>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings/Offering"/>
        </OfferingsWithCourse>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Offering">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:variable name="webinars" select="accumulator-after('webinars')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="offered-lessons" select="accumulator-after('offered-lessons')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('webinars'))[. = map:keys($offered-lessons)]">
                <xsl:variable name="webinar-id" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$webinars(.)[not(. = $offered-lessons($webinar-id))]">
                    <Error>No matching required lesson found for title {.} in Course num {$webinar-id}</Error>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        
    <xsl:template match="Lesson">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Offering/Lesson">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        
    <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
            <xsl:if test="Course-Number = ''">
                <Error>
                    <xsl:text>Missing required field Course Number. </xsl:text>                                    
                </Error>
            </xsl:if>                         
            <xsl:if test="Facilitator-LDAP = ''">
                <Error>
                    <xsl:text>Missing required field Facilitator LDAP for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
                </Error>
            </xsl:if> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Location[normalize-space() and not(map:contains(accumulator-before('location-map'), string()))]">
       <xsl:next-match/>
       <Error>Mapped location not found for {.}</Error>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Location[normalize-space() and map:contains(accumulator-before('location-map'), string())]">
       <xsl:next-match/>
       <MappedLocation>{accumulator-before('location-map')(.)}</MappedLocation>
    </xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thant really helpd me Martin . Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, you could get into the habit of accepting answers on StackOverflow once they helped.