# xslt 3.0 based on a condition insert child node

Tags: xml, xslt, streaming, xslt-3.0

I have a requirement to insert a child node in xslt when a condition is satisfied
i,e when a offered course is present in Source course . Kndly refer the
Source xml and My xslt in below link

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74339222/xslt-3-0-mapping-and-validation
```

Added a child node  which is a copy of Learning course. This child node must be present for each offerring with corresponding course data i.e when the offered Course-Number is present in Source xml

```
 <!-- Matching course-->
                                
                                <xsl:if test="exists($LearningCoursesMap(current()/Lesson[1]/Course-Number))">
                                    <CourseDetails>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="$LearningCoursesMap(current()/Lesson[1]/Course-Number)"/> 
                                    </CourseDetails>
                                </xsl:if>
```

Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfferingsWithCourse xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Offering>
        <Lesson>
            <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
            <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
            <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
            <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</Title>
            <Facilitator-LDAP>AXH4006</Facilitator-LDAP>
            <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
            <Location/>
            <Room>Ottawa District Training Center</Room>
            <InstructorID>119417764</InstructorID>
            <MappedLocation/>
            <MappedRoom>LOCATION-6-3881</MappedRoom>
        </Lesson>
        <Lesson>
            <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
            <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
            <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
            <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</Title>
            <Facilitator-LDAP/>
            <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
            <Location>7070</Location>
            <Room>Ottawa District Training </Room>
            <InstructorID/>
            <MappedLocation/>
            <MappedRoom/>
            <Error>Missing required field Facilitator LDAP for at least one of the lessons in the
                offering. </Error>
            <Error>Mapped location not found for 7070. </Error>
            <Error>Mapped room not found for Ottawa District Training . </Error>
        </Lesson>
        <CourseDetails>
            <wd:Learning_Course xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2b24f4f5c40000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">00151744</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:ID>
                </wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                <wd:Learning_Course_Data>
                    <wd:ID>00151744</wd:ID>
                    <wd:Effective_Date>2014-10-04</wd:Effective_Date>
                    <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                    <wd:Course_Title>Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:Course_Title>
                    <wd:Description>Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:Description>
                    <wd:Course_Number>00151744</wd:Course_Number>
                    <wd:Topic_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d1f49654c8310154e239c7090fc0000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Topic">Product Knowledge - US</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Topic_Reference>
                    <wd:Language_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da594226446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="User_Language_ID">en_US</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Language_Reference>
                    <wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>0</wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                    <wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>0</wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                    <wd:Waitlist_Capacity>0</wd:Waitlist_Capacity>
                    <wd:Unlimited_Capacity>1</wd:Unlimited_Capacity>
                    <wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                        <wd:Pricing_Enabled>0</wd:Pricing_Enabled>
                        <wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>0</wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>
                    </wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                    <wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f31be4fd5caa10001d7c625e27014929</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Time_Unit_ID">HOURS</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                    <wd:Total_Course_Duration>18</wd:Total_Course_Duration>
                    <wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>0</wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>
                    <wd:Legacy_Course>1</wd:Legacy_Course>
                    <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df56ab318140000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">100735117</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018bbed7a460ce30000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">119417764</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df57b8e81f30002</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">104034590</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:All_Locations>0</wd:All_Locations>
                    <wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>1</wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>
                    <wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>0</wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>
                    <wd:Disable_Express_Interest>1</wd:Disable_Express_Interest>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>1</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>2</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 2</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>3</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>4</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 4</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>5</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 5</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>6</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 6</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>7</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Media_Reference>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2b23247d3f0004</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">MEDIA-6-4195</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">MEDIA-6-4195</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Welcome to HDU Distance
                                Learning</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                            <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                        </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>8</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>0</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Media_Reference>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">358e28e73d5d10109aef5b042fc20000</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">cninv000000000020562.zip</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">cninv000000000020562.zip</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Course Feedback
                                HDUv3</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                            <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                        </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Learning_Course_Data>
            </wd:Learning_Course>
        </CourseDetails>
    </Offering>
    <Offering>
        <Lesson>
            <Offering-ID>00170024CA - 2022 Group 12 - Thurs 10AM-1PM EST</Offering-ID>
            <Course-Number>00170024CA</Course-Number>
            <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
            <Title>Session 4</Title>
            <Facilitator-LDAP>TXB786</Facilitator-LDAP>
            <Webinar-URL>https://hdu-canada.adobeconnect.com/design_basics_2/</Webinar-URL>
            <Location>Laval</Location>
            <Room/>
            <InstructorID>713400041</InstructorID>
            <MappedLocation>7070</MappedLocation>
            <MappedRoom/>
        </Lesson>
        <Lesson>
            <Offering-ID>00170024CA - 2022 Group 12 - Thurs 10AM-1PM EST</Offering-ID>
            <Course-Number>00170024CA</Course-Number>
            <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
            <Title>Session 5</Title>
            <Facilitator-LDAP>ZXF99S</Facilitator-LDAP>
            <Webinar-URL>https://hdu-canada.adobeconnect.com/design_basics_2/</Webinar-URL>
            <Location>Laval</Location>
            <Room/>
            <InstructorID/>
            <MappedLocation>7070</MappedLocation>
            <MappedRoom/>
            <Error>Instructor ID not found for Workday account ZXF99S. </Error>
        </Lesson>
        <CourseDetails>
            <wd:Learning_Course xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2c78dc802e0001</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">00170024CA</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">Design Basics (Designer Training 4) - Virtual
                        ILT</wd:ID>
                </wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                <wd:Learning_Course_Data>
                    <wd:ID>00170024CA</wd:ID>
                    <wd:Effective_Date>2019-02-26</wd:Effective_Date>
                    <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                    <wd:Course_Title>Design Basics (Designer Training 4) - Virtual
                        ILT</wd:Course_Title>
                    <wd:Description>&lt;p&gt;In this 5 module virtual course the designer will learn
                        the basics of drafting and laying out basic designs for Contractors and DIY
                        customers.&lt;/p&gt;</wd:Description>
                    <wd:Course_Number>00170024CA</wd:Course_Number>
                    <wd:Topic_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d1f49654c8310154e4430e071ef0000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Topic">Customer Service and Selling Skills -
                            CAN</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Topic_Reference>
                    <wd:Language_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da5948c0446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="User_Language_ID">en_CA</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Language_Reference>
                    <wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>4</wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                    <wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>10</wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                    <wd:Waitlist_Capacity>0</wd:Waitlist_Capacity>
                    <wd:Unlimited_Capacity>0</wd:Unlimited_Capacity>
                    <wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                        <wd:Pricing_Enabled>0</wd:Pricing_Enabled>
                        <wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>0</wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>
                    </wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                    <wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f31be4fd5caa10001d7c6231be3b4927</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Time_Unit_ID">MINUTES</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                    <wd:Total_Course_Duration>900</wd:Total_Course_Duration>
                    <wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>0</wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>
                    <wd:Legacy_Course>1</wd:Legacy_Course>
                    <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5cfa198ca0000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">718700459</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5c99611170000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">713400041</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5c72adbc60000</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">702300581</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:All_Locations>0</wd:All_Locations>
                    <wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>1</wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>
                    <wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>0</wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>
                    <wd:Disable_Express_Interest>1</wd:Disable_Express_Interest>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>1</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Session 1</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>2</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Session 2</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>3</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Session 3</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>4</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Session 4</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>5</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Title>Session 5</wd:Title>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                            <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                        </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>6</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Media_Reference>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2c770c4c2b0003</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">MEDIA-6-4222</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">MEDIA-6-4222</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Log in Instructions (Adobe Connect -
                                Designer 4_DesignBasics) (updated May
                                2022)</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                            <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                        </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Lesson_Order>7</wd:Lesson_Order>
                        <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>0</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                        <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                            <wd:Media_Reference>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">358e28e73d5d1010910342e9c79a0000</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">cninv000000000019226.zip</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">cninv000000000019226.zip</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Course Evaluation - vILT
                                (L1)</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                            <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                        </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                    </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Learning_Course_Data>
            </wd:Learning_Course>
        </CourseDetails>
    </Offering>
</OfferingsWithCourse>
```

---

A capturing accumulator for your data would be (with `xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"` declared on the stylesheet)

```
<xsl:accumulator name="learning-courses" as="element(wd:Learning_Course)*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule saxon:capture="yes" match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course" phase="end" select="$value, ."/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

then you could change the template matching `Offering` to

```
<xsl:template match="Offering">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:variable name="webinars" select="accumulator-after('webinars')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="offered-lessons" select="accumulator-after('offered-lessons')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('webinars'))[. = map:keys($offered-lessons)]">
            <xsl:variable name="webinar-id" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$webinars(.)[not(. = $offered-lessons($webinar-id))]">
                <Error>No matching required lesson found for title {.} in Course num {$webinar-id}</Error>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:where-populated>
          <CourseDetails>
            <xsl:copy-of select="accumulator-after('learning-courses')[wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID = map:keys($offered-lessons)]"/>
          </CourseDetails>
        </xsl:where-populated>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Check whether the version of Saxon you use supports capturing accumulators https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensions/attributes/capture.html, that way you can rather easily store a copy of nodes in accumulators and access them later, although of course that way, if you turned to streamed processing because the traditional XSLT 2 or 3 processing run out of memory with large or huge input documents, once you capture lots of complex node structures in accumulators (instead of lightweight maps with few, selected values) you run the risk of running out of memory again.

Comment: yes, there is huge data and traditional xslt is  processing too much time

Comment: I m trying to add a child node <CourseDetails> in    <Offering> and i used a accumulator match-courses but i m getting some error . I need to check a condition that is the Offering/Lesson/Course-Number is present in the source xml /FileAndCourses/AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Number
The code is posted in answer section with a comment <!-- Trying to insert Child node in Offering-->kindly help on this

Comment: Tell us exactly which error you get if you expect us to help resolving that particular error. And at least in your question it seems you want to pull in complete XML input nodes like `wd:Learning_Course` from the "beginning" of the XML into the "end" (e.g. a `Lesson` element), to be able to do that I pointed you to some Saxon extension attribute and the relevant part of its documentation, also requesting you to check which Saxon EE version you use. Without that information it doesn't make sense to try to write code as in the past most people using XSLT with workday data only had access to 9.7.

Comment: And as far as I remember Saxon 9.7 EE didn't support `saxon:capture` on accumulators.

Comment: @ChrisTucker please note in general that streaming solves your problem if you're running out of memory. It is unlikely to solve a problem of execution time, unless there's some algorithmic change. And rather than describing your data as "huge", which could mean anything from 1Mb to 1Tb, please tell us its size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes"
  version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="location-internal-value" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations/Location" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations/Location/InternalValue/text()" select="."/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="location-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations" select="map{}"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Locations/Location/ExternalValue/text()" 
          select="map:put($value, string(), accumulator-before('location-internal-value'))"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="Room-internal-value" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Rooms/Room" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Rooms/Room/InternalValue/text()" select="."/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="Room-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Rooms" select="map{}"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Maps/Rooms/Room/ExternalValue/text()" 
          select="map:put($value, string(), accumulator-before('Room-internal-value'))"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="Instructor-internal-value" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Instructors/Instructor" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Instructors/Instructor/InstructorID/text()" select="."/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="Instructor-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Instructors" select="map{}"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Instructors/Instructor/WorkdayUserName/text()" 
          select="map:put($value, string(), accumulator-before('Instructor-internal-value'))"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="learning-course-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID/text()" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="lesson-mandatory" as="xs:boolean?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data" select="false()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory/text()" select=". = 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="webinars" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
          select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
          return
          if (map:contains($value, $id))
          then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
          else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  <xsl:accumulator name="classroom-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
          select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
          return
          if (map:contains($value, $id))
          then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
          else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lesson-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Course-Number/text()" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering" select="map{}"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Title/text()" 
          select="let $id := accumulator-before('offered-lesson-id')
          return
          if (map:contains($value, $id))
          then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
          else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="match-courses" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID/text()"
          select="let $id := accumulator-before('offered-lesson-id')
          return
          if (map:contains($value, $id))
          then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
          else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/FileAndCourses" expand-text="yes">
      <OfferingsWithCourse>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings/Offering"/>
      </OfferingsWithCourse>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Offering">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
          <xsl:variable name="webinars" select="accumulator-after('webinars')"/>
          <xsl:variable name="offered-lessons" select="accumulator-after('offered-lessons')"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('webinars'))[. = map:keys($offered-lessons)]">
              <xsl:variable name="webinar-id" select="."/>
              <xsl:for-each select="$webinars(.)[not(. = $offered-lessons($webinar-id))]">
                  <Error>No matching required lesson found for title {.} in Course num {$webinar-id}</Error>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
<!--            Trying to insert Child node in Offering-->
          <xsl:variable name="match-courses" select="accumulator-after('match-courses')"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('match-courses'))">
              <CourseDetails>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="Lesson[1]/Course-Number"/> 
              </CourseDetails>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
      
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Lesson">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Offering/Lesson">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <!-- Validation Errors for Lessons --> 
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
          <xsl:if test="Course-Number = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Course Number. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>                         
          <xsl:if test="Facilitator-LDAP = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Facilitator LDAP for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if> 
          <xsl:if test="Offering-ID = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Offering ID. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>  
          <xsl:if test="Start-Date = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Start Date for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="Start-Time = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Start Time for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="End-Time = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field End Time for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="Title = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Title for at least one of the lessons in the offering. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>  
          <xsl:if test="Webinar = 'Y' and Webinar-URL = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field Webinar URL for webinar type lesson. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>  
          <xsl:if test="Webinar != 'Y' and Location = ''">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Missing required field location for classroom type lesson. </xsl:text>                                    
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>   
          <!-- Validation errors for Offering: validating same value for min seat, max seat, and language -->
          <xsl:if test="Lesson/Min-Seats != Lesson/Min-Seats">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Different values found for field Min Seats among the lessons. Min Seat should be the same for all the lessons within the same offering.</xsl:text>                          
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="Lesson/Max-seats != Lesson/Max-seats">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Different values found for field Max Seats among the lessons. Max Seat should be the same for all the lessons within the same offering.</xsl:text>                           
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="Lesson/Language != Lesson/Language">
              <Error>
                  <xsl:text>Different values found for field Language among the lessons. Language should be the same for all the lessons within the same offering.</xsl:text>                           
              </Error>
          </xsl:if>
          
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--    Mapped location-->
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Location[normalize-space() and not(map:contains(accumulator-before('location-map'), string()))]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <Error>Mapped location not found for {.}</Error>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Location[normalize-space() and map:contains(accumulator-before('location-map'), string())]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <MappedLocation>{accumulator-before('location-map')(.)}</MappedLocation>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--    Mapped Room-->
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Room[normalize-space() and not(map:contains(accumulator-before('Room-map'), string()))]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <Error>Mapped Room not found for {.}</Error>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Room[normalize-space() and map:contains(accumulator-before('Room-map'), string())]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <MappedRoom>{accumulator-before('Room-map')(.)}</MappedRoom>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--    Mapped Instructor -->
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Facilitator-LDAP[normalize-space() and not(map:contains(accumulator-before('Instructor-map'), string()))]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <Error>Mapped Instructor not found for {.}</Error>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson/Facilitator-LDAP[normalize-space() and map:contains(accumulator-before('Instructor-map'), string())]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <MappedInstructor>{accumulator-before('Instructor-map')(.)}</MappedInstructor>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--    No intructor-led webinar lesson found in course with title:-->
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'Y'][let $webinars := accumulator-before('webinars') return if (map:contains($webinars, Course-Number)) then not(Title = $webinars(Course-Number)) else false()]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
          <Error>
              <xsl:text>No intructor-led webinar lesson found in course with title: </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
              <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
          </Error>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--    No intructor-led classrom lesson found in course with title:-->
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'N'][let $lessons := accumulator-before('classroom-lessons') return if (map:contains($lessons, Course-Number)) then not(Title = $lessons(Course-Number)) else false()]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
          <Error>
              <xsl:text>No intructor-led classrom lesson found in course with title: </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
              <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
          </Error>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--    Unable to find active course-->
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'Y'][not(map:contains(accumulator-before('webinars'), Course-Number))] | Lesson[Webinar = 'N'][not(map:contains(accumulator-before('classroom-lessons'), Course-Number))]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
          <Error>
              <xsl:text>Unable to find active course </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Course-Number"/>
              <xsl:text> in Workday. </xsl:text>
          </Error>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'Y'][not(map:contains(accumulator-before('webinars'), Course-Number))] | Lesson[Webinar = 'N'][not(map:contains(accumulator-before('classroom-lessons'), Course-Number))]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
          
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It helps to explain your answer.